# Treat One File Type Like Another in Eclipse for Formatting and Syntax Highlighting?

Tags: eclipse, formatting

We are currently using [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) and some of the files are just standard HTML files but have the extension `.vm` which means that they aren't recognized as HTML files and hence don't have syntax highlighting etc.

Is there a way to force a certain file type extension to be treated as another file type within Eclipse? For example our `.vm` files to be treated like `.html` files so correct syntax highlighting and code formatting is used by Eclipse.

Is there a built in way to do this or would I need to get a plugin to add this type of functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `*.vm` to the HTML content type in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types.

[image: setting a content type]

Then associate the file type with an editor in Window -> Preferences -> Editors -> File Associations. The default editors for HTML files are associated automatically by the content type.

[image: associate with editor]